# AngularJS animate div on scope update

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

I'm trying to animate a div with some content whenever the $scope variable is updated. I want to give the user feedback that an update has occurred.

In my controller I update the $scope through a websocket like this:

```
socket.syncUpdates('item', $scope.items, function(event, item, array) {
    $scope.items = array;
});
```

I can't get my head around how to do this. I'm using ng-animate and animation.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
socket.syncUpdates('item', $scope.items, function(event, item, array) {
    $scope.items = array;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

In your syncUpdates, trigger `$digest` cycle using `$apply()`.

Now you can do animation in two places. Either do it inside this `syncUpdates` itself below the `$scope.$apply()` else in a separate `$watch`.

```
$scope.$watch("items", function(newValue, oldValue) {
     // your animation code here
}, true);
```

To animate the div, Here is one sample:

```
myApp.animation(".fade", function () {
  return {
    addClass: function (element, className) {
      TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 0});
    },    
    removeClass: function (element, className) {
      TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 1});
    }
  }
})
```

In your controller:

Inject `$animate` inside your controller function. Then use

```
    $animate.addClass(document.querySelector("selector"), "fade");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it out, do you have an example with using animate.css? Also this doesn't use the ng-animate at all does it?

Comment: check this one: https://thinkster.io/egghead/animating-the-angular-way it will be useful